# Heißt es "online gehen", "online schalten" oder "online stellen"

Tags: anglicism

nachdem eine Website lokal, also offline entwickelt wurde, setzt man meistens einen Termin für das "Go-Live" fest, den Zeitpunkt, zu dem die Website ins Netz gestellt werden soll.
Jetzt frage ich mich, was das deutsche Verb dazu ist: online gehen (oder onlinegehen?), online schalten (oder onlineschalten?) oder online stellen (onlinestellen?) oder vielleicht doch etwas ganz anderes?

Comment: Wie immer eine Frage des Kontexts: _Das Angebot schaltet online_, _Wir gehen das Angebot online_ und _Das Angebot stellt online_ sind jedenfalls alle falsch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In deinem Kontext sind alle drei richtig. *Online gehen* und *online stellen* haben noch zwei andere Bedeutungen. Ersteres kann auch einfach bedeuten, dass ich mich über einen Provider ins Internet einwähle, letzteres kann auch verwendet werden, wenn ich Daten (z.B. Bilder) im Netz (öffentlich) ablege.

Letzteres ist schon sehr nahe an deinem Kontext, wo es ja nicht nur Daten sind, sondern ein ganze Webseite oder ein Webangebot. Entsprechend kann man natürlich auch diese *online stellen*. Und wenn man die Webseite auf einen Server hochlädt und im Anschluss den Zugang öffentlich ermöglicht, *schaltet* man seine Seite *online*. Und die Tatsache, dass man nun im Internet 'vorhanden' ist, kann ausgedrückt werden, als dass man *online gegangen* ist.

> Wir gehen online. Wir schalten unsere Webseite online. Wir stellen unsere Webseite online.

Anmerkung: Man kann übrigens auch Anträge online stellen, das ist aber wieder was ganz anderes.

Comment: "Ins Internet einwähle", sehr schön :)

Comment: Und wieder hab ich Modempfeifen im Ohr =D

Comment: Als ergänzung: "Die Website ist nun aufgeschalten" wäre auch eine möglichkeit

Answer (score 5):

Wir nutzen es folgendermaßen in usnerer IT-Umgebung:

> Unser Team geht mit der Webseite live.
>
> Unser Team stellt die Seite online

`onlineschalten` geht auch, aber ich habe die Variante selten gehört.

Darüber hinaus, das Wort `Livegang` wird auch bei uns aktiv benutzt.

Comment: "Mit etwas live gehen" würde ich als übliches Marketing-Bla bezeichnen. Im Deutschen geht man nicht dies und das - vielleicht frühstücken, nach Hause, Sport treiben.

Comment: @Roman T: Diese Antwort ist auch sehr nützlich, weil es mich auch interessierte, welcher Ausdruck denn tatsächlich im "wirklichen Leben" von IT-/Webentwicklungs-Unternehmen benutzt wird.

Answer (score 0):

Das richtige Wort wäre "Produktivsetzung". [Hier](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Testaufwand) steht ein Beispiel.

> Diese schließen auch die Kosten für die Qualität in der Softwareerstellung (siehe "statisches Testen") ein. Ebenso gehören im Besonderen die aktiv ausgeführten Tests (= "dynamische Testarten") - aus Sicht des Projektziels "Produktivsetzung" - zur Fehlervermeidung.

[Andere Beispiele.](http://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/uebersetzung/produktivsetzung.html)

Aber wie immer mit Technologie, kann das englische Wort auch verwendet werden.

Mann kann das Wort auch als Verb verwenden. Produktivsetzen. Aber ziemlich formell.

Comment: Gesucht ist ein Verb. Ginge _eine Webseite wird produktiv gesetzt_?

Comment: Ja. Siehe hier: http://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/search?source=auto&query=produktiv+gesetzt

Comment: Vielleicht mag *Produktivsetzung* in Informatikerkontexten korrekt sein – mir stellt es die Nackenhaare auf.

Comment: Oder schmucklos: ... wird aktiviert. Spektakulärer: Wir schalten das Angebot heiß. Gemäßigt: ... schalten es frei, schalten es an, aktiv setzen.

Comment: @Jan Mir auch, und ich bin Informatiker...

Comment: @Jan in real life auch nie gehört :)